# how to add rows of info to dictionary with a dataframe for the value, and a symbol for the key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have multiple csv files each containing rows of stock companies and columns containing info about that stock. each file is representing stock info for 1 day. I have added all of the csv files to a dataframe using:

```py
path = "path to csv files"
filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
final_df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames))
```

then I stored each unique company symbol into an array using:

```py
enter code here
uSym = final_df.Symbol.unique()
```

then I created a dictionary with a structure that is key is unique symbol, value is dataframe with columns that I'm interested in:

```py
symDict = {}
for el in uSym:
    symDict[el] = pd.DataFrame(columns = [['Open','High','Low','Close', 'YTD%Chg']])
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to populate the values for each dataframe in my dictionary with each row from my original dataframe for each symbol. I have included an image to show each row for symbol FCCY in the original dataframe, id like to add all of the rows to values in my FCCY key:

[image: data frame and dictionary example]

Comment: Why not incorporate the symbol into your index with a multi-index?  More generally than your specific question, what are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: thank you for replying. what i am trying to do in the end is a forecast on the stock market using historical data. the idea is that i can get the unique ticker, and create a new csv for each symbol and store the rows of information from each seperate file into that 1 csv. then i can add a date to sort and use it for my time series.
@RagingRoosevelt

Comment: What's the benefit of sending this data back to a CSV rather than leaving it in pandas?  Using pandas columns for input to a ML model shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: i suppose not, so instead could i somehow add a date column to my original dataframe that has values that match the format of the title of each csv file in my original folder. and example file name is NYSE-Thursday-August-02-2018. then i could use my original data frame and sort by date to use in my time series. to be honest importing the data so it can be used is what i struggle with. this is my first time doing a time series.
@RagingRoosevelt

Comment: yeah, IMO it'd be way easier to leave it as a dataframe and just embed the date column.  it'd be especially easy if you used a normal for loop rather than a list comprehension, but if you kept the list comp, you could do something like `final_df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f).assign(Date=f[5:]) for f in filenames))`

Comment: i was actually trying looping without list comprehension while waiting for your response.  tis is the code i tried after reading your response. it does give an error stating "first argument must be in an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type Dataframe."
   for f in filenames:
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f).assign(Date=f[5:])).
previously i just had:
for f in filenames:
 df = pd.read_csv(f)
@RagingRoosevelt

Comment: `pd.concat` needs the argument to be an iterable of pandas objects, so list, tuple, etc. In the statement you have, you'd need to surround the dataframe with `[pd...., ]` or `(pd...., )`.  In the loop approach, you'd need to set up an empty var (`df_all = None`), then concat each new df into that: `for  f in filenames: df_all = pd.concat([df_all, pd.read_csv(f).assign(Date=f[5:])])`.

Answer (score 0):

you can append the data to your `symDict`

```
for el in symDict.keys():
    symDict[el].append(final_df.loc[final_df['Symbol']==el], symDict[el].columns])
```

or add it directly when you were creating the `symDict` variable

```
symDict = {}
for el in uSym:
    # symDict[el] = pd.DataFrame(columns = [['Open','High','Low','Close', 'YTD%Chg']])
    sysmDIct[el] = final_df.loc[final_df['Symbol']==el, ['Open','High','Low','Close', 'YTD%Chg']]
```

Comment: thank you kindly for answering that @Gusti